# EMongoCriteria does not have a method named "name"

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, conditional-statements, criteria

On yii app, I am creating EMongoCriteria from array like the following:

```
$mongoCriteria["conditions"] = array("name"=>new MongoRegex("/John/i"));
$criteria = new EMongoCriteria($mongoCriteria);
```

As I understood there is no proper way to make the following case insensitive:

```
$mongoCriteria["conditions"] = array("name"=>array("==" => "John"));
```

That is why I am using MongoRegex. Also I need to make it "contains" similar to LIKE operator in mysql. For some reason I have to create conditions in array first, so I cannot use this:

```
$criteria->name = new MongoRegex('/John/i');
```

The problem is that it is not working and showing this error:

```
EMongoCriteria does not have a method named "name"
```

Please any ideas?

I have tried this as well, the same problem:

```
$mongoCriteria["conditions"] = array("name"=>array("regex" => new MongoRegex("/John/i")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the following:

```
$mongoCriteria["conditions"] = array("name"=>array("==" => new MongoRegex("/John/i")));
```

I did not know == operator would work with regex, because it was not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: You can use EMongoCriteria::OP_EQUALS as a constant for ==